# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. warning is displaued in protractor console on using aync and await

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I have written the below code for automation using protractor.

```
this.promoteToOperationaltSandboxes3 = async function(){


        const allMainPanel =  element.all(by.className('tropos-appbox-main-panel col-md-12'));
        console.log(typeof allMainPanel);

        console.log('In the wait function , number of the main panels is '+allMainPanel.length);
const allLitags = await allMainPanel[0].all(by.className('dropdown-menu ng-scope')).all(by.tagName('li'));
        console.log('In the wait function , number of the litags is '+allLitags.length);
}
```

i am calling this function in one of my spec file  like this.

```
await appsPage.promoteToOperationaltSandboxes3();
```

On executing this function even the browser is not opening and giving the erorr as ;

> Message:
>       TypeError: Cannot read property 'all' of undefined   Stack:
>       TypeError: Cannot read property 'all' of undefined

Also, in the logs i can see the message as :

> In the wait function , number of the main panels is undefined.

can anyone help me in resolving these issue and help me in handling the promise better.

Comment: Are you sure that all the awaits are against function calls that return a promise ?  i.e. what are you expecting to get back from this :
allMainPanel[0].all(by.className('dropdown-menu ng-scope')).all(by.tagName('li')); ?

Answer (score 3):

you should change the `allMainPanel` to get the index there first:

```
const allMainPanel =  element.all(by.className('tropos-appbox-main-panel col-md-12')).get(0);
```

then the `allLitags` as well, maybe into 2 separate variables:

```
const allLitags = allMainPanel.all(by.className('dropdown-menu ng-scope'));
const liElement = await allLitags.all(by.tagName('li'));
```

Comment: This seems correct. You cannot access elements in an `elementArrayFinder` using `[]` you must use [.get()](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.get). Simply changing `allMainPanel[0]` to `allMainPanel.get(0)` may be sufficient to resolve your issue